# ASP.net Base64 image string doesn't display when using variable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, base64, razor-pages

I have been having a problem trying to display an image from a DB. The image is encoded as a Base64 string (TXT), in the DB.

The problem is when trying to set the HTML  src to the base64 string, using the string variable Image, it wouldn't display. However, the same base64 string will display when directly adding it to the src.

The below code is what is used to display the image. The only difference between the 2  is, the first one pull the Base64 string from the image variable and the second one has the string directly copied into src.

Thank you for any help :).

```
<div class="card-img-top">
    @{
        if (gear.Image != null)
        {
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, @gear.Image" alt="Image of @gear.Name">
        }
        else
        {
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Image of @gear.Name"/>
        }
    }
</div>
```

What is shown between the 2 images when the page is displayed:

The variable version:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

When the base64 string is copied into img src:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: When you look at the developer tools of your browser, what do you see as the rendered source?

Comment: @Marco When loading the page I get a console error saying "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL"

Comment: If you opened the HTML source, what the HTML element for this img look like? you will know if both imgs have the same values or not.

Comment: @WajdyEssam This is with the HTML:

Form the variable src:
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="


Directly copied in: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="